# web application shows blank page after deployment on heroku?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku

I create web app using `reactjs`, `nodejs` and `postgres` and its working fine on localhost, then I deployed it on `heroku` and it builds successfully but when I open it using heroku link it returns me `blank page` and When I see in `browser console I see some errors`, error is common and repeat  10 times. Errors are

[image: Error in console displays in image]

**My project structure is:**

```
Rootfolder/
/client
      /build
      /static
          /css
          /js
      /node_modules
      /public
      /src
         /css
            myform.css
            hrcss.css
      /component (this folder contains all my reactjs that is fronent files)
   /routes
   package.json
   Server.js
```

**index.html**(client/build/)

```
<!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="utf-8"/><link rel="icon" href="./favicon.ico"/><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous"><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous"><link rel="stylesheet" href="../src/css/myform.css"/><link rel="stylesheet" href="../src/css/Hrcss.css"/><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"/><meta name="theme-color" content="#000000"/><meta name="description" content="Web site created using create-react-app"/><link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="./logo192.png"/><link rel="manifest" href="./manifest.json"/><title>React App</title><link href="./static/css/main.305b25b3.chunk.css" rel="stylesheet"></head><body><noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript><div id="root"></div><script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script><script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script><script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script><script>!function(e){function r(r){for(var n,l,a=r[0],f=r[1],i=r[2],c=0,s=[];c<a.length;c++)l=a[c],Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(o,l)&&o[l]&&s.push(o[l][0]),o[l]=0;for(n in f)Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(f,n)&&(e[n]=f[n]);for(p&&p(r);s.length;)s.shift()();return u.push.apply(u,i||[]),t()}function t(){for(var e,r=0;r<u.length;r++){for(var t=u[r],n=!0,a=1;a<t.length;a++){var f=t[a];0!==o[f]&&(n=!1)}n&&(u.splice(r--,1),e=l(l.s=t[0]))}return e}var n={},o={1:0},u=[];function l(r){if(n[r])return n[r].exports;var t=n[r]={i:r,l:!1,exports:{}};return e[r].call(t.exports,t,t.exports,l),t.l=!0,t.exports}l.m=e,l.c=n,l.d=function(e,r,t){l.o(e,r)||Object.defineProperty(e,r,{enumerable:!0,get:t})},l.r=function(e){"undefined"!=typeof Symbol&&Symbol.toStringTag&&Object.defineProperty(e,Symbol.toStringTag,{value:"Module"}),Object.defineProperty(e,"__esModule",{value:!0})},l.t=function(e,r){if(1&r&&(e=l(e)),8&r)return e;if(4&r&&"object"==typeof e&&e&&e.__esModule)return e;var t=Object.create(null);if(l.r(t),Object.defineProperty(t,"default",{enumerable:!0,value:e}),2&r&&"string"!=typeof e)for(var n in e)l.d(t,n,function(r){return e[r]}.bind(null,n));return t},l.n=function(e){var r=e&&e.__esModule?function(){return e.default}:function(){return e};return l.d(r,"a",r),r},l.o=function(e,r){return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(e,r)},l.p="/";var a=this.webpackJsonpema=this.webpackJsonpema||[],f=a.push.bind(a);a.push=r,a=a.slice();for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)r(a[i]);var p=f;t()}([])</script><script src="./static/js/2.c570e064.chunk.js"></script><script src="./static/js/main.cbcc4cc1.chunk.js"></script></body></html>
```

**package.json** (from root directory)

```
{
  "name": "backend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "engines": {
    "npm": "6.x",
    "node": "12.18.2"
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "start": "node Server.js",
  "heroku-postbuild": "cd client && npm install && npm run build",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "client": "npm run start --prefix client",
    "server": "nodemon Server.js",
    "dev": "concurrently --kill-others-on-fail \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"",
    "start": "node Server.js",
    "heroku-postbuild": "cd client && npm install && npm run build"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "pg": "^8.3.0",
    "pg-hstore": "^2.3.3",
    "restify": "^8.5.1",
    "restify-cors-middleware2": "^2.1.0",
    "sequelize": "^6.3.3",
    "sequelize-cli": "^6.2.0",
    "serve-static-restify": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.4"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/path.git"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/path"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/path",
  "description": ""
}
```

**Server.js**

```
var restify=require('restify')
const { logIn,userCreation, demotable } = require('./routes/Function');
const corsMiddleware = require('restify-cors-middleware2');
const { data } = require('jquery');
const PORT=process.env.PORT || 8080;
var path=require('path')
var serveStatic = require('serve-static-restify')
var server=restify.createServer() //server created

server.use(
    function crossOrigin(req,res,next){
      res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
      res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
      res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true); // If needed
      res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
      res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
      res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
      return next();
    }
  );
const cors = corsMiddleware({
  preflightMaxAge: 5, //Optional
  origins: ['*'],
  allowHeaders: ['*'],
  exposeHeaders: ['*']
})

server.pre(cors.preflight)
server.use(cors.actual)

console.log(__dirname);
console.log(path.join(__dirname, "client/build"));
server.post('/', userCreation);  
server.use(restify.plugins.bodyParser());
server.get('/login',logIn)
server.get('/employees',demotable)


if(process.env.NODE_ENV==='production')
{
  server.get("*", restify.plugins.serveStatic({
    directory: __dirname+"/client/build",
    default: 'index.html',
    appendRequestPath: false
   })
  );
}
server.listen(PORT, function(){
    console.log("server started...")

})
```

And heroku logs doesnot show any errors but it shows status 404 for all files which gives error in browser console.
**heroku log sample**

```
2020-08-10T17:38:57.167522+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/css/main.a8c455be.chunk.css" host=deployableema.herokuapp.com request_id=82757ef5-eeff-4640-b435-0414e90c2f80 fwd="157.47.17.61" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=4ms status=404 bytes=700 protocol=https
```

Answer (score 0):

`404` is the error code for "file not found", and in your case, those CSS and JS files aren't being found because the hashed CSS and JS filenames produced by your webpack config for production builds do not match the filenames that your HTML file requests.

Try building in production mode on your local machine. This will help you debug the issue.

Comment: Thanks for replying `simmer`, but I am new in development , so can you clarify me what I need to do because I didnot understand what you told me in your first comment

Comment: Sure. The javascript and CSS you write get run through a "preprocessing" step, which can do things like whitespace compression, rewriting cutting-edge JS syntax to be compatible with older browsers, etc. When you deploy to Heroku, those preprocessors are run in "production" mode, which potentially modifies your files in a different way from your local development mode. In your case, one of the things that's happening in production mode is that processed files are renamed for cache-busting purposes, resulting in files named like `main.625332d7.chunk.js`.

Comment: There's a lot for you to learn here. I suggest reading up on Webpack and how to understand the `scripts` section of your `package.json` file, as a start.

Comment: Thank You Simmer for replying